# How do I update Logstash data to Redshift real-time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, logstash, pipelining, elk

I am looking for a way to build a pipeline for storing the logs data (I use the ELK stack) to AWS Redshift, for analytics.

I have gone through the Output plugins for ElasticSearch, and [found one](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-s3.html) for writing data to AWS S3. But, it writes data in batches and dealing with S3 is slow.

So, is there any way I can build a pipeline from my ELK stack to Redshift for my logs data?

Update: The ELK stack cluster is hosted on an EC2 VPC

Comment: I'm sure you could write an output plugin to do so.

Comment: @womble Seems like that's the only way to go.

You can delete my answer, or leave it as is.  If latter, then I can visit it to self-answer with the method which I have implemented.